# How to Deploy a Maven Project with CXF Web Services on WebSphere (WAS 7.0) Using RAD 8.0

Tags: maven, websphere, cxf, ibm-rad

I need to know how to create a Maven project with CXF web services/facets in Rational Application Developer (RAD) 8.0 that can be deployed on WebSphere Application Server (WAS) 7.0.

I have tried starting off with an enterprise application project or a dynamic web application (with CXF facet enabled) then converting it to Maven -- it *did not* work. I decided to create a Maven project first, then adding a CXF facet (**2.7.7**), Dynamic Web Module (**2.5** -- 3.0 does not work with combination of application server, web module, CXF, etc.), and WebSphere Web/WebSphere Extended, and changing WebContent folder to src/main/webapp to adhere to the Maven structure.

This allowed me to have an EAR project generated which is required for deployment on WAS 7.0. However, upon building the project (either through Maven Install or through Project -> Build Project), I get an error in the web.xml file:

```
The servlet mapping "CXFServlet" refers to a servlet that is not defined    web.xml    /WSProvider/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF    Unknown    Web Problem
```

The content of **web.xml** along with ibm-web-bnd.xmi and ibm-web-ext.xmi (I had to renamed them from .xml to .xmi due to versioning) are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <description>CXF Application</description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:com/b4interview/ws/conf/beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**ibm-web-bnd.xmi**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

</web-bnd>
```

**web-ibm-ext.xmi**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />

</web-ext>
```

And if I try to deploy the application as is, I get this from the logs:

```
The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start. View the Details to display the exceptions and server logs that occurred during the publish.  

======== WSProviderEAR ========

Failed to add or remove the application from the server: WSProviderEAR
[11/23/13 23:12:55:888 CST] 00000047 wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleFileImpl processNoSuchClassException Annotations scanning of archive [ WSProvider.war ] completed with errors.  Could not find class [ org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder ].
[11/23/13 23:12:56:171 CST] 00000047 wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl getDeploymentDescriptor An error occurred while processing the deployment descriptor, error message=IWAE0007E Could not load resource "WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml" in archive "WSProvider.war"
[11/23/13 23:12:56:183 CST] 00000047 FfdcProvider  I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_50135013_13.11.23_23.12.56.17835875.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.ExtensionHelper.processServerInstallExtensions 193
[11/23/13 23:12:56:247 CST] 00000047 FfdcProvider  I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_50135013_13.11.23_23.12.56.19535876.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run 297
[11/23/13 23:12:56:251 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/application.xml
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ResourceLoadException: IWAE0007E Could not load resource "WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml" in archive "WSProvider.war"
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.WrappedRuntimeException: Exception occurred loading WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1$DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtensionInExistingResource(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtension(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.helper.CommonExtensionsHelper.getExtension(CommonExtensionsHelper.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext.WebAppExtensionsHelper.getWebAppExtension(WebAppExtensionsHelper.java:64)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ArchiveSchedulerImpl.getArchive(ArchiveSchedulerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.getEarFile(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.isclite.deploy.task.IscTaskProvider.provideServerInstallExtensions(IscTaskProvider.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ExtensionHelper.processServerInstallExtensions(ExtensionHelper.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.setupTasks(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:272)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getPackageForURI(XMLHandler.java:2330)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getFactoryForPrefix(XMLHandler.java:2168)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectByType(XMLHandler.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createTopObject(XMLHandler.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXWrapper.startElement(SAXWrapper.java:90)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
    ... 24 more

[11/23/13 23:12:56:251 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R Stack trace of nested exception:
[11/23/13 23:12:56:252 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.ResourceLoadException: IWAE0007E Could not load resource "WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml" in archive "WSProvider.war"
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.WrappedRuntimeException: Exception occurred loading WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1$DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtensionInExistingResource(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtension(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.helper.CommonExtensionsHelper.getExtension(CommonExtensionsHelper.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext.WebAppExtensionsHelper.getWebAppExtension(WebAppExtensionsHelper.java:64)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ArchiveSchedulerImpl.getArchive(ArchiveSchedulerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.getEarFile(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.isclite.deploy.task.IscTaskProvider.provideServerInstallExtensions(IscTaskProvider.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ExtensionHelper.processServerInstallExtensions(ExtensionHelper.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.setupTasks(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:272)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getPackageForURI(XMLHandler.java:2330)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getFactoryForPrefix(XMLHandler.java:2168)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectByType(XMLHandler.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createTopObject(XMLHandler.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXWrapper.startElement(SAXWrapper.java:90)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
    ... 24 more

[11/23/13 23:12:56:252 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R Stack trace of nested exception:
[11/23/13 23:12:56:253 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.WrappedRuntimeException: Exception occurred loading WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi
Stack trace of nested exception:
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1$DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtensionInExistingResource(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd.AbstractTraversalHelper.getBindingOrExtension(AbstractTraversalHelper.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.helper.CommonExtensionsHelper.getExtension(CommonExtensionsHelper.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext.WebAppExtensionsHelper.getWebAppExtension(WebAppExtensionsHelper.java:64)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:441)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ArchiveSchedulerImpl.getArchive(ArchiveSchedulerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.getEarFile(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.isclite.deploy.task.IscTaskProvider.provideServerInstallExtensions(IscTaskProvider.java:54)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.ExtensionHelper.processServerInstallExtensions(ExtensionHelper.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.setupTasks(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:272)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getPackageForURI(XMLHandler.java:2330)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getFactoryForPrefix(XMLHandler.java:2168)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectByType(XMLHandler.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createTopObject(XMLHandler.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.SAXWrapper.startElement(SAXWrapper.java:90)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:264)
    ... 24 more

[11/23/13 23:12:56:253 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R Stack trace of nested exception:
[11/23/13 23:12:56:253 CST] 00000047 SystemErr     R org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1$DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
...
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found. (file:///C:/Program%20Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xmi, 6, 16)
```

Which apparently points to the following missing schema "**Package with uri 'http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee' not found.**"

Comment: This looks like a product issue to me.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: @bkail I can deploy a Dynamic Web Module with CXF facet on WAS 7.0 through RAD 8.0 (it was verified by someone else). I had to manually add the WAS "runtime" JDK to the config path libraries. The issue is the _Mavenization_ of the project -- bean objects not instantiating properly. I have to come back to it eventually and will share the solution if I'm lucky. Thanks.